# How to make a program separate words by the end of the word?

Tags: python, names, letters

I know the question sounds a little tricky or not really clear but I need a program, which would separate names. Since I am not from an English speaking country, our names either end in **s (for males)** or in **e and a (for girls)**

How do I make Python separate words by their last letter?
I guess this would explain more.

Like there are three names: `"Jonas", "Giedre", "Anastasija".`
And I need the program to print out like this

```
MALE: Jonas
FEMALE: Anastasija, Giedre
```

I started up the program and so far I have this:

```
mname = []
fname = []
name = input("Enter a name: ")
```

That's really all I can understand. Because I'm not familiar with how to work the `if` function with the last letter.

Answer (score 3):

You could use negative indexes to acess the last element of the string

```
name = input("Enter a name: ")
if name[-1] in ('a','e'):
    fname.append(name)
elif name[-1] == 's': 
    mname.append(name)
```

[image]

As you can see, `-1` is the last character of a string.

Quoting from the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

> Indices may also be negative numbers, to start counting from the
>   right:
>   `>>> word[-1]  # last character 'n'`

Answer (score 0):

If you're entering the names at once, you'll need to split them by whitespace checking the ends:

```
names = input('Enter names: ') # string of names to split by spaces
fname = [n for n in names.split() if n[-1] in ('a', 'e')] # females
mname = [n for n in names.split() if n[-1] == 's'] # now male names
```